# Backup services on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon

What backup services are there that run through AmazonWS accounts?

I see ImageCloudLock, but the 'solution url' for this service leads to an error page, so I guess this product is not current.

Are there any others? I don't see any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storage services I know that use S3 are:

- [JungleDisk](https://www.jungledisk.com/) can use either Amazon S3 or RackSpace Cloudfiles as its backing store.
- smugmug (a photo-hosting service) has an optional [Smugvault](http://help.smugmug.com/customer/portal/articles/93324) feature that allows you to store non-image files, and it's backed by S3.
- Amazon Cloud Drive - 20 GB is $20/year, the first 5 GB is free, though I don't think there are very nice automated clients like, say, JungleDisk, for using it.

Now, if you're thinking of using Amazon S3 as a literal backup, it might not be very cost effective. 1 GB is $0.14 USD to store, plus you pay for put/get requests (though for backups, probably not significant). 10 GB is $1.40, 100 GB is $14, and so on until you start crossing the terabyte tier where prices start dropping per gigabyte.

Storing a small amount of data would be fine, but if you're talking about significant storage, there are plenty of alternatives, depending on your needs.

There are plenty of alternatives that are much more economical once you start scaling up your storage needs:

Backup-style services - these are ones that actually are about backing up your data, in case your computers explode and you need to get your data:

- CrashPlan - they use their own internal storage cloud
- BackBlaze - same, internal storage pods
- Carbonite

More dropbox-y type services, where your files can be retrieved

- Spideroak - zero-knowledge storage, you buy storage in blocks, at $10/month per 100 GB
- UbuntuOne

And more, like Wuala and Windows LiveDrive.

Comment: Thanks birryree. Those Amazon prices you mention: 1 GB is $0.14 USD to store... there's also this: http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/ -- it says First 1 TB / month is $0.125 per GB -- and that's labelled 'Storage Pricing' -- is that not an applicable product for this?

Comment: @Richard - Sorry, the $0.14 is for Jungledisk's rate if you use S3. If you directly use S3, then it's 12.5 cents per GB per month. If you were to just get your own S3 account and wanted to manage it yourself, you can use a client like [CloudBerry S3 Explorer](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-amazon-s3-explorer-cloudfront-IAM.aspx) to move files to/from S3.